# Getting Bot Response using Middleware in Bot Framework using Python

Tags: python, azure, botframework, middleware

I need help in creating a middleware for my bot created using bot framework in python so that it captures bot responses. If there is any reference material also available in Python, please let me know?

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-inspection-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python

Answer (score 0):

[BOT middleware pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) might help here for gathering the responses.

We can understand more about Middleware from Microsoft documentation.

To get better understanding about the inspection with middleware, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-inspection-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python).

Coming to the code to meet your requirement, we have [Microsoft bot builder sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/README.md) where we can find multiple methods and codes to interact with bot services based on our requirements

As you have mentioned about sending and receiving the response this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python) might help, also more from the Develop section from this link.